# Rendering and navigating multiple charts in highcharts

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, highcharts

I'm working on an exercise to plot multiple charts in one page. I would like to use the navigator to pan through these data.

Is there a way I could navigate 10+ multiple charts simultaneously more smoothly? 
The more charts I have the more sluggish it becomes.

Also if the data set becomes too large, when moving the navigator the data seems to jump out the plotting area rather than slowly translating outside the plotting area.

Please see the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alanchang87/3753vt85/)

```
function afterSetExtremes(event) {
var globalMax = event.max;
var globalMin = event.min;

for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
  charts[i].xAxis[0].setExtremes(globalMin, globalMax, true, false);
}
```

---

[3 Charts](https://alanchang87.tinytake.com/sf/MTY5NTg0Nl81NjQ3MTcz) running seems to be able panning smoothly. (Points move out of the viewing window point by point)

[12 Charts](https://alanchang87.tinytake.com/sf/MTY5NTgzOF81NjQ3MTU1) seems to struggle panning smoothly. The effect I'm seeing is that chucks of data gets move out the viewing window instead translating by points.

** Click hyperlinks to see the videos **

Any suggestions to this will be grateful. Thanks

Comment: Try to set [scrollbar.liveRedraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar.liveRedraw) to false. The charts will not be re-rendering constantly on navigator dragging. If the 'freeze' is too long, you can add some kind of loading animation - you can use setExtremes and aferSetExtremes to achieve it. I cannot reproduce the issue with jumping out data.

Comment: [3 Charts](https://alanchang87.tinytake.com/sf/MTY5NTg0Nl81NjQ3MTcz) Please see the example in the video, when there are only three charts running,as panning. The data seems to be able translating point by point out of the viewing window. 
Where as [12 Charts](https://alanchang87.tinytake.com/sf/MTY5NTgzOF81NjQ3MTU1), as panning the data gets translated out of viewing in chunks.

Comment: Set liveRedraw to false https://jsfiddle.net/3753vt85/12/. You can open a ticket on github tracker and describe the issue https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: For the exercise, I'll required to have liveRedraw functionality.